# re-use views on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I can't find a way to use views from other views.

I think I can explain it better with this example: I have two controllers, `IndexController` and `UserController`. The user controller has an action called `login` with its view which renders the login form and validates the user when a post from its form happens.

In `IndexController`, there is an action called `home` which renders the home page view. In this view I want to render the `loginform`, but I want to re-use the user/login view.

In almost all the frameworks I worked with there is a way to call another controller action in order to re-use and isolate the logic.

I find that, in Rails, there is a helper `render` that I can call in the following way:

```
render 'user/login'
```

or

```
render :template => 'user/login'
```

In both cases I only get errors like "the route index/login does not exist" or "the controller index has to login action". Besides, I set the login view file name as `login` or `_login`. (I read that is used for partial views.)

Comment: use partials and include them in your standard views

Comment: The default partial template dir is `RAILS_ROOT/app/views/shared`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Railscast: "[#269 Template Inheritance](http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance)".

Since Rails 3.1, controller inheritance now applies to views as well. This is preferred over the older "shared folder" strategy.

In short, you put your shared partials in `app/views/application` then you can override them in your resource specific view directories (e.g `app/views/users`).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by creating a shared folder within your views folder and create the login form as a partial.

So your login partial might be something like this.

/app/views/shared/_loginform.html.erb:

```
<div id="loginform">        
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
      <%= f.submit "Login" %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="loginlinks">
      <%= link_to "Become a member", new_member_registration_path %> <br />
      <%= link_to "Forgot Password?", new_member_password_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your views just call:

```
<%= render "shared/loginform"  %>
```

Comment: thanks, it was very usefull but i think i will use the template ineritance proposed by gylaz.